# Instant Application publish error: The default URL "https://xxxl.com" is not mapped to your Instant application

Tags: android, instant

1.I had add [default url](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html#default-url)  "https://example.com" on LAUNCHER Activity;

2.used App Links Assistant Test All is Ok([Associate](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html?utm_source=android-studio#associatesite) website is OK);

play store tip:The default URL "https://example.com" is not mapped to your Instant application?

What was problem?

Comment: I have solved it.Thanks

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Can you answer what fixed the issue?

Comment: @CHF can you please answer how u fixed.. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @ adnanyousafch,@ Murtuza Saifee, add default url in install App  and instant App(feautre-base) AndroidManifest.xml. it will solved the issue.     Note: both url must be the same

Answer (score 1):

in the installed module: app/manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.example.MainActivity">

        <meta-data
                android:name="default-url"
                android:value="https://example.com/app" />
 </activity>
```

And the same metadata in your feature manifest