# Google Play Instant Apps with Navigation Component: The default URL “https://example.com” is not mapped to your Instant application

Tags: android, navigation, androidx, android-instant-apps

I have an already published Instant App in Google Play Store, and I have migrated it to Navigation Components.

I have removed the intent filter from the manifest as the Navigation Components adds them for you. However, Google Play is showing me this error:

`The default URL “https://example.com” is not mapped to your Instant application`

This is my previuos intent filter:

```
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="example.com"
                    />
            </intent-filter>
```

And this is the generated manifest after adding material components navigation:

[image: navigation merged manifest]

What is causing the Google Play error?

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678954/instant-application-publish-error-the-default-url-https-xxxl-com-is-not-map).

TL:DR One of these solutions should work:

1. Add default URL in install App and instant App(feature-base) AndroidManifest.xml.

Or

2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50462921/13372062

Comment: I have a default url. It works without Navigation Component